# Unable to get response from promiese with recursively calling the function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

working with node.js Q promises library i am in doubt that is it useful with recursively calling a function. I had tried two approaches to solve my problem.In 1st approach i tried to returns directly from recursive function And in 2nd approach i tried with Q promise library.

Here is my code from where i am calling that recursive function and expecting response here.

```
function getSearchedUserInTree(userId,body){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var loggedInUserId = userId;    
    var searchUserIdSql =  "SELECT rc.user_id,CAST(b.node_id AS CHAR) AS node_id FROM refer_codes AS rc LEFT JOIN btrees AS b ON b.user_id=rc.user_id WHERE rc.refer_code='"+body.refer_code+"'";
    connection.query(searchUserIdSql, function (err, result,field) {        

        var getLoggedInNode = "SELECT CAST(b.node_id AS CHAR) AS node_id FROM btrees as b WHERE b.user_id='"+loggedInUserId+"'";
        connection.query(getLoggedInNode, function (err, loggedResult,field) {
            helper.trackRelation(loggedResult[0].node_id,result[0].node_id,function(err,relationResult){
                if(err) throw err;
                deferred.resolve(relationResult);
            });
        });        
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

1st approach to get return from "trackRelation()" function with promises.

```
function trackRelation(parentNode,childNode){
  var deferred = Q.defer(); 
  var childNodeId = bigInt(""+childNode+"");
  var parentNodeId  = bigInt(""+parentNode+"");
  if(bigInt(childNodeId).compare(parentNodeId) == 0){        
    var childSql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='"+childNodeId.toString()+"'";
    connection.query(childSql,function(err,packResult,field){
      console.log(packResult);
      deferred.resolve({status:200,message:'success',packResult});
    });
  }else{
    /* Detact position */
    if(bigInt(childNodeId).mod(2) == 0){
      var tempParentNodeId = bigInt(childNodeId).divide(2);
    }else{
      var subResult = bigInt(childNodeId).subtract(1);
      var tempParentNodeId = subResult.divide(2);
    } 

    /** If reached at top but parent not found **/
    if(bigInt(tempParentNodeId).compare(1) == 0){
      var childSql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='"+tempParentNodeId.toString()+"'";
      connection.query(childSql,function(err,packResult,field){
        console.log(packResult);
        deferred.resolve({status:200,message:'success',packResult});        
      });
    }else{
      return trackRelation(parentNodeId,tempParentNodeId.toString());
    }

  }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

2nd approach to get return from recursively function with directly return value without promises.

```
function trackRelation(parentNode,childNode){      
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      var childNodeId = bigInt(""+childNode+"");
      var parentNodeId  = bigInt(""+parentNode+"");      
      if(bigInt(childNodeId).compare(parentNodeId) == 0)
      {               
        deferred.resolve({status:200,message:'success',topUserId:childNodeId.toString()});
        return childNodeId.toString();
      }else
      {
        /* Detact position */
        if(bigInt(childNodeId).mod(2) == 0){
          var tempParentNodeId = bigInt(childNodeId).divide(2);
        }else
        {
          var subResult = bigInt(childNodeId).subtract(1);
          var tempParentNodeId = subResult.divide(2);
        }

        /** If reached at top but parent not found **/
        if(bigInt(tempParentNodeId).compare(1) == 0){          
          return tempParentNodeId.toString();
        }else
        {
          return trackRelation(parentNodeId,tempParentNodeId.toString());
        }
      }
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

I didn't get any response from both of these approaches. i tried to print values which i need in response in console and i got that value same as desired but unable to get that value in response.

Comment: In the `else` case, you never call `deferred.resolve`

Comment: In my first approach i had already used deferred.resolve({status:200,message:'success',packResult}); . Is it not a correct way to use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the value back from a promise the way you get back from a callback.

Your method `trackRelation` returns a promise whose values should be accessed using the `.then()` method.

Example:

```
trackRelation(args).then(function(res){
     //when the promise resolves, this method is called
}, function(err){
     //when the promise rejects, this method is called
});
```

Check the API reference page [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference).

Comment: Thanks Parijat for your answer, that actually works for me. can you please explain what i did wrong and how to solve such kind of problems in node.js.  And one more thing, can you tell me how can i stop that recursion after getting desired result ?

Comment: as you said it worked for you, I'll just explain briefly.. you did `trackRelation(args,callback)` for a function which returns a promise. Instead if you do `trackRelation(args).then(passCallback, failCallback)`, it should work fine. As far as recursion is concerned, if you wish to work with recursive promises, let the recursive promise resolve and then resolve the current promise.
What I mean is to do something like:

`else{trackRelation(parentNodeId,tempParentNodeId.toString(),function(res){defer.resolve(res);})}`